# Find problem rows in GDB_ITEMS_VW

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, error, oracle-dbms, domains, geodatabase-xml

*Oracle 18c 10.7.1 EGDB:*

---

Oracle GDBs have a view called [GDB_ITEMS_VW](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/overview-geodatabase-system-tables.htm#:%7E:text=data%20type.%20The-,GDB_Items_vw,-shows%20the%20contents) that has a `DEFINITION` column with extracted XML values (clob).

I can extract data, such as coded value domains, from the XML column using queries like the following:

```
select      
    i.name as domain_name,
    x.code as code,
    x.description as description
from        
    sde.gdb_items_vw i
cross apply xmltable(
    '/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue' 
    passing xmltype(i.definition)
    columns
        code        varchar2(255) path './Code',
        description varchar2(255) path './Name'
    ) x  

DOMAIN_NAME          CODE                 DESCRIPTION                             
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------
ATN_MATERIAL         A                    ASPHALT                                 
ATN_MATERIAL         O                    ASPHALT CAPPING                         
ATN_MATERIAL         B                    BRICK    
...
```

When I run that query in SQL Developer, it runs without errors, but that's just because it's only selecting the first 50 rows.

If I try to run the query on all rows (via CTRL+END), then it throws an error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

---

Is there a way to determine what specific XML rows are causing that error?

Answer (score 0):

I can create a function to wrap the call that is causing issues and catch the exception in the function:

```
with function test_xmltable(v_xml clob) return number
is
  v_code SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  v_desc SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
begin
  SELECT code, description
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_code, v_desc
  FROM   xmltable(
           '/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue' 
           passing xmltype(v_xml)
           columns
             code        varchar2(255) path './Code',
             description varchar2(255) path './Name'
         );
  return 1;
exception
  when others then
    return 0;
end;

select i.name as domain_name,
       test_xmltable(i.definition) as passed_xml_test
from   sde.gdb_items_vw i
where  test_xmltable(i.definition) = 0;
```

```
Result:

DOMAIN_NAME     PASSED_XML_TEST
--------------- ---------------
(null)                        0
```

---

So, the problem was a row that is mostly nulls.

From now on, I'll add `where i.name is not null` to my queries to avoid the error.

Source: [Determine what rows are causing error in query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72453748/5576771)

Comment: I don't know how that null row got in that system table. We've never meddled with the system tables using SQL or anything like that.