# Select domain codes/descriptions using XMLTABLE instead of EXTRACTVALUE

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, domains, geodatabase-xml

*Oracle 18c 10.7.1 GDB:*

---

The ArcGIS system table docs have an example for extracting domain codes and descriptions from XML:

[Example: Resolving domain codes to description values using SQL](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/example-resolving-domain-codes-to-description-values.htm)

```
--simplified:
select
    extractvalue(codedvalues.column_value,'CodedValue/Code') as domain_code,
    extractvalue(codedvalues.column_value,'CodedValue/Name') as domain_description
from
    sde.gdb_items_vw items
cross join 
    xmlsequence(xmltype(definition).extract('/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue')) codedvalues
where
    items.name is not null
```

That example uses the EXTRACTVALUE function to get domain codes and descriptions.

But when I look the Oracle docs, they say this about EXTRACTVALUE:

> [Oracle 11g R2 docs:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173)
>
> The EXTRACTVALUE function is deprecated. It is still supported for
> backward compatibility. However, Oracle recommends that you use the
> XMLTABLE function, or the XMLCAST and XMLQUERY functions instead.

So instead of using EXTRACTVALUE, I want to use XMLTABLE, since that's what Oracle recommends. And also because XMLTABLE is said to be significantly faster: [Oracle Database XMLTable vs ExtractValue performance](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/03/15/oracle-database-xmltable-vs-extractvalue-performance/)

---

Question:

How can I use XMLTABLE to get domain codes and descriptions from GDB_ITEMS_VW?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
--create or replace view d_all_coded_value_domains_vw as 
select      
    cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum_,
    x.code,
    x.description,
    i.name as domain_name
from        
    sde.gdb_items_vw i
cross apply xmltable(
    '/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue' 
    passing xmltype(i.definition)
    columns
        code        varchar2(255) path './Code',
        description varchar2(255) path './Name'
    ) x    
where      
    i.name is not null --https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434701/find-problem-domains-in-gdb-items-vw
```

Performance: I did a comparison between the old EXTRACTVALUE and the new XMLTABLE queries. XMLTABLE was twice as fast as EXTRACTVALUE (10 seconds vs. 5 seconds). So XMLTABLE is a clear winner.